# Create VirtoCommerce custom API endpoint with VC platform API Authentication

Tags: virtocommerce

like the title says, I want to extend the VC platform API endpoints with the built in API Authentication (via the API key).

I followed the tutorial to create a managed module, and I can successfully make the API calls. However, it doesn't include any authentication. I am wondering how would I accomplish this?

Another question is that in order to have the VC Storefront to use my custom API endpoints, I would have to generate the module API using the AutoRest on the VC Storefront project, correct?

Thnak you all in advance!

Comment: Do I understand the issue correctly: you want your API to be restricted, but now you can access it anonymously. Correct?

Comment: I was actually mistaken. It turned out that I was logging as admin on the VC platform, and tried the API call. Once I cleared the cookie, I can no longer call the API. Yesterday, I actually exposed the custom API endpoints to the VC storefront, and I got the successful return from the API. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

VC uses platform API with [APIRequestHandler](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront-core/blob/b9516c7533b9533d088f6f22f9c623494cbb2311/VirtoCommerce.Storefront/Infrastructure/Autorest/VirtoCommerceApiRequestHandler.cs), that uses ApppId and SecretKey to add header to every API request:

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("HMACSHA256", signature.ToString());
```

Then handler is used by every endpoint - [link to code](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront-core/blob/b9516c7533b9533d088f6f22f9c623494cbb2311/VirtoCommerce.Storefront/DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtension.cs#L68).

More info on authentication could be found here:
[Working with platform API](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/working-with-platform-api).

> Another question is that in order to have the VC Storefront to use my custom API endpoints, I would have to generate the module API using the AutoRest on the VC Storefront project, correct?

Yes, correct.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you for the reply. I actually got it working. I was misunderstood how the module worked. I forgot the module was installed to the Platform and all the endpoints are access via Platform API, so the authentications should work with it. I can all the my endpoints through the Storefront app now :) Thanks!